# Multiple domains

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I work on a Laravel and AngularJS project and I would like to access to my project with different domain because I use different servers.
The domain name of my first server is :

```
http://examplesite/
```

The domain name of my second server is :

```
https://examplesite/subfolder/
```

For the first I have no problems, but I have a problem for the second when I called a route in my AngularJS code like on this example :

```
$http.get("/load-documents")
```

Normaly the request must to be like this :

```
https://examplesite/subfolder/load-documents
```

but she is like this without the subfolder :

```
https://examplesite/load-documents
```

And it's possible that in the future I use another servers with more or less subfolders.

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: `The domain name of my second server is : https://examplesite/subfolder/` - no, that is not a _domain name_, that is a URL. Perhaps you should start by making yourself aware what the difference is.

Comment: Artisan server.

Comment: @VivienTouly If you are using apache server, use virtual hosts or create a sub domain and do it, like http://example.com and for api use http://api.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a subdomain?

Otherwise, since you are talking about using different servers, each server can have different environment variables. So, if you set the correct `url` in `config/app.php`, or `APP_URL` in the environment, Laravel will use it as a base path. Then make sure you then set the base URL in the HTML:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <base href="{{ config('app.url') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    ..
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm not familiar with how Angular handles a `get` request, but using the base href is the expected behavior.